# jquery: Add class if link has a target blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

hey guys,
shouldn't that work?

```
//Add class if target blank
    $('.post .entry a').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).attr('target') == '_blank') ) {
            $(this).addClass('web');
        };
    });
```

anything wrong with this?

Comment: `target="_blank"` is an annoyance. Besides that, better use a selector like `a[href*="//"]` (assuming only external links are absolute, i.e. `http://someurl` or `//someurl`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try

```
//Add class if target blank
$('.post .entry a[target="_blank"]').addClass('web');
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nicer way of writing the same. But have you answered the question?

Answer (score 7):

You have an extra `)`. Just remove that and it's fine :)

```
$('.post .entry a').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('target') == '_blank') ) {
---------------------------------------------^
        $(this).addClass('web');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. But this should be inside a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.post .entry a').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).attr('target') == '_blank') ) {
            $(this).addClass('web');
        };
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: instead of $(document).ready(function(){...}) you can use $(function(){...})

Answer (score 2):

You have am extra `)` on the if statement. Take that off an you'll be ok:

```
$('.post .entry a').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('target') == '_blank' ) {
        $(this).addClass('web');
    };
});
```

A shorter way to do this would be:

```
$('.post .entry a[target="_blank"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('web');
});
```

Uses less code too.

Actually @ariel's answer states a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is a nicer way of writing the same. But have you answered the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found success with the following:

```
$('.post .entry a[href="_blank"]').addClass('web');
```